# Loop Through All Data, Create Object, Output, Repeat

Tags: javascript, object, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am creating a google script that pulls event data from a google sheet and creates an event schedule on another sheet.

**The Data**: The event data is stored in a google sheet with the following columns: `Event Start, Event End, Event Name, Event Role, Event Worker`. A data row in the sheet generally looks like this: `6/23/2018 | 6/28/2018 | Holiday Party | Event Manager | Christopher Smith`.

The data is really used as a way for the event workers to know when they are working and what their role will be. There are multiple workers working each event so there is a different row for each worker.

**The Question**: The javascript below works pretty good; it loops through all the data, creates the event object, checks if it is the correct event type, checks the event start date and compares it to the event schedule dates, and then inserts the data in the correct spot on the event schedule. **However, it only does it for the last row of data.** What I am having trouble with is how to start at the top of the data, build the first event object, insert that data on the schedule, and then repeat the process on the next event in the data.

```js
//Event object
var event = {
  id: null,
  start: null,
  end: null,
  workers: [],
};

//Loop through data and get event details      
for (var i = 1; i < dataDates.length; i++) {
  if (dataDates[i][3].indexOf("Manager")) {
    event.id = dataDates[i][0] + dataDates[i][2];
    event.start = dataDates[i][0];
    event.end = dataDates[i][1];
  }
}

//Loop through data and group workers together (grouped by specific event)
for (var ii = 1; ii < dataDates.length; ii++) {
  if (dataDates[ii][0] + dataDates[ii][2] == event.id) {
    event.workers.push(dataDates[ii][4]);
  }
}

//Add the event data to the event schedule sheet   
for (var iii = 1; iii < gridDates.length; iii++) {
  if (gridDates[iii][0] == event.start) {
    grid.getRange(iii + 1, 2, 1).setValue(event.workers);
  }
}
```

Comment: You are doing far too many loops for what I think you are trying to do. This could all be done elegantly in one function perhaps. However, its not entirely clear exactly what it is that you are doing (atleast for me).

Comment: @Daniel Zuzevich thanks for your reply! I'm just trying to create an event calendar from a spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I'm understanding your question properly, I think the problem here is that you only ever have one event object, and your first for loop just goes over each row in your data and continually reassigns the values of the id, start and end keys in that event object. At the end of this loop you have one object where the id, start and end keys contain only values from the last row in your data. This then means your conditional statements in the 2nd and 3rd for loops are not having the desired effect because they are only reacting to the one event object containing only data from your last row.

Comment: I am fully aware of the issue. I was hoping for help with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The reason no one has probably answered this yet, is that your question, although crafted neatly, lacks proper details for us to help you in an adequate manner. 
For example, really what you should include is a sample data structure that the Google Sheets API returns to you.

From what it looks like, it returns you a 2D array. Perhaps something like this?

```
var dataDates = [
  ['6/23/2018', '6/28/2018', 'Holiday Party', 'Event Manager', 'Christopher Smith'],
  ['7/23/2018', '7/28/2018', 'Hawaiian Shirt Day', 'Event Manager', 'John Doe']
];
```

Keith was right, in the sense that you are only creating one event object, and you are overwriting that object every time you go through your loop. Instead, you need to create an object for every single row in your loop.

It still is unclear why you are doing so many loops, and why you cant achieve all of this inside of one single loop, but I will help you get on the right track, and then hopefully we can refine this answer until you ultimately solve it. Keep in mind, what I am suggesting is not an efficient algorithm, but like I said, I still am not seeing exactly what you need to do.

**Start of the Solution:**
Instead of creating one event object, lets create a new one for every single pass through the initial for loop, like so:

```
var dataDates = [
  ['6/23/2018', '6/28/2018', 'Holiday Party', 'Event Manager', 'Christopher Smith'],
  ['7/23/2018', '7/28/2018', 'Hawaiian Shirt Day', 'Event Manager', 'John Doe']
];

// We will store all the dynamically created event objects in this array
var allEvents = [];

// Loop through each row and create an object on the fly, and push it to allEvents
for(var i = 0; i < dataDates.length; i++) {
  var event = {
    id: null,
    start: null,
    end: null,
    workers: []
  };

  if(dataDates[i][3].indexOf('Manager')) {
    event.id = dataDates[i][0] + dataDates[i][2];
    event.start = dataDates[i][0];
    event.end = dataDates[i][1];
  }

  allEvents.push(event);
}
```

Notice how I create an empty array outside of the loop named allEvents. This is going to store all of your newly created event objects inside the for loop. After the first for loop finishes, lets execute another for loop, that iterates through allEvents like so:

```
for(var i = 0; i < allEvents.length; i++) {
   if(dataDates[i][0] + dataDates[i][2] == allEvents[i].id) {
     allEvents[i].workers.push(dataDates[i][4]);
   }
}
```

What this will do, is update your allEvents array to now include the correct worker inside of each object.

**Additional Comments**
Again, I am unsure as to why you cant do all of the following in one loop,

- Create an event object for each row WITH workers included (no need for second loop)
- Append that event object into the new Google Sheet

Hopefully you can comment on this answer and clarify as to why you think you need multiple loops.

**PS**
Your third for loop makes reference to a gridDates array that you did not tell us about, or provide details to what it may contain.

Please do not take my criticisms personally, it is all intended to help you craft better questions on Stack Overflow in the future.

I have included a working [Codepen](https://codepen.io/DZuz14/pen/eKGoqm?editors=0012) for you to check out some of the ideas I mentioned above.